# Image not loading in react native having bearer token authentication

Tags: react-native, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-403, bearer-token

I am having my images on a secure server. For authentication, I should provide a bearer token. If I pass it using the below format I am getting a blank image.

```
<Image
source={
{ uri: 'https://yourdomain.com/get-image',
  headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer xyz'
           }
        }
 }/>
```

When I have checked error code onError prop in Image source it has

> "nativeEvent": {"error": "Unexpected HTTP code 403"}

I have tested the request in postman it is working without any issues.(I am able to see the image)

The token is valid.

Edit1: Sending an XMLHttpRequest and taking the byte array and converting it into Base64 works just fine.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, pls post the solution if it resolved

Answer (score 0):

`"nativeEvent": {"error": "Unexpected HTTP code 403"}`

The 403 error HTTP status code meaning access to the requested resource is forbidden for some reason.

I think your token bearer is not correct

Comment: The token is valid. There is no issue with the token. The request is working perfectly fine in postman.

Comment: @eoeo Im having the same issue. Were you able to resolve it?